# Is ripple effect/radical reaction possible on switchcompat?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design, switchcompat

I was trying to apply radical reaction/ripple effect on switch compat, however the most I could get out of it was a short effect. I have a switch within a row ,which I would like to highlight throughout the row once switch is flipped on and off. Currently the only thing that highlights is the switch that too not a ripple effect, just like a dull highlight on the switch itself. Is it possible to send out a wave/ripple effect throughout the entire row once the switch is flipped?
here's my code:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/altercolor2"
         android:padding="@dimen/common_padding">

        <com.myapp.utils.FontTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/common_top_padding"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/common_bottom_padding"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title"
            foo:customFont="proxima-nova-regular.ttf"
            android:text="@string/display_image" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/display_image_toggle_control"
            foo:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Switch"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/toggle_margin_leftright"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own ripple effect, create a `drawable-v21` folder and put following drawable as a background of your `FrameLayout` I guess fix your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/gray_light">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@color/gray" />
</ripple>
```

Also add:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

> Is it possible to send out a wave/ripple effect throughout the entire
>   row once the switch is flipped?

I think you need to set`foreground` and `background` in your Views.

Comment: the above framelayout is contained within a <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/altercolor2" >  , what do i add in  foreground and background ,also where do i add the focusable in the switch or in the framelayout containing it?

Comment: add focusable and clickable to your root.

Comment: how do i increase the diameter of the ripple effect, current it seems to die off half way?

Comment: You can add size to your ripple drawable [ use android:constantSize="true"] and set your size;
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: that still doesnt help the radius increase, it just goes to half the size with the existing code, do you have any code sample on switch?